# How to grab filter elements form a large search result when just using smaller pages in the application?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a search query that returns a bunch of records but we're using paging so we only return back 10, 25, or 50 page subsets of the data.  Basically the stored procedure goes along these lines.

```
WITH search_results AS
(
    SELECT model, brandname, msrp,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @sortExpression) as rowNumber
    FROM models
    WHERE ...criteria....
)

SELECT * FROM search_results
WHERE rowNumber BETWEEN ((@pageNumber-1)*@pageSize)+1 and ((@pageNumber-1)*@pageSize)+@pageSize
```

When I use small pages my sproc comes back very quickly, usually in under a second.  However, sometimes our users will enter criteria that may return back a few thousand to potentially a ten thousand records.  They'll page through and just grab a few at a time, but the actual search results have a large number.  The sproc is running quickly when my page size is small but when I increase it, it takes a few seconds which is too long.

This is all fine, I am using smaller pages.  The problem is that part of our solutions is a filter.  This filter lists all of the brands, categories, and 4 price range quadrants for the full search results.  So when they click filter it takes the lowest price and and the highest, breaks it into 4 equal sized groupings and they are on the form with checkboxes.  user than can check the ranges they want to filter and the brands and categories they want to filter.  This re-submits the search with new criteria.

I'm not sure how to return a full set of brands, categories and highest/lowest price without running the main procedure (in the WITH) twice.  Does it make sense to dump all of that into a temporary table and then return back multiple recordsets to my business object?  The results, the brand list, the category list, and then the MIN and MAX prices?   Is there a pattern for returning back filter information for search results like this?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, there's no pattern and maybe. Try to put the raw big result in a temp table and use it to return multiple record sets. Test it and see if it works better. Doing it you are (in general) using more memory and less CPU. In the tunning business sometimes there are trade offs where you can exchange memory/IO/CPU use to speed up things.